# permutation which involves 4^18 permutations with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am pretty new at coding with MatLab, so, I could only think of basic codes.

I want to solve this problem, say I have `18` bags of balls, each bag contain `4` balls, each ball has a number.

But every `6` bags of balls are exactly the same.

Say bags are

```
A,B,C,D,E,F
A:0,1,2,3
B:0,4,5,6
C:0,7,8,9
D:0,10,11,12
E:0,13,14,15
F:0,16,17,18
```

And another `12` bags with similar contents.

So now I want to pick a ball from each of the `18` bags, then I add the numbers up, the sum will be in the range of `0` to `189`, but ignore `0`, and just use `1` to `189`.

Now, I want to know what is the probability of getting each of the sum ranging from `1` to `189`. I know the denominator is `418` - a large number.

I initially wanted to just use `18` loop-within-loopss in Matlab to find the sum, and then create a `189` entry vector where I would +1 in the respective entry for the sum.

However, I realized that that `18` loops means `4^18` computations, which I feel is unreasonable, so, can someone tell me a better algorithm to solve this?

My old code look like this:

```
vector = 
[1 0 1 2 3]
[2 0 4 5 6]
[3 0 7 8 9]
[4 0 10 11 12]
[5 0 13 14 15]
[6 0 16 17 18]
:::::::
[18 0 16 17 18]

probability = zeros(1,189)

for (a=1:4) 

for (b=1:4)

for (c=1:4)

for (d=1:4)

for (e=1:4)

:::::

for (r=1:4)

sum =vector(1,a)+vector(2,b)+vector(3,c)+vector(4,d)+vector(5,e)+vector(6,f)+....+vector(18,r)
probability (sum) = probability (sum)+1
```

Comment: What about [perms](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) or anyother avaliable function for combinatios/permutations, e.g. [combn](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-combn--4-3-)

Comment: If you have the structure that every 6 bags are the same you should use that.

Comment: I do not mean that this question should be removed from here, but I would recommend you that in addition to this you could submit a question to [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/). That question can then focus on the mathematical problem. I do not say that people here are bad on maths, but you would most likely get better help with mathematical problems there. It is likely that the problem can be simpified in some way to reduce the computational complexity.